# NotImplementedExecption was unhandled! STUCK!

Tags: c#, .net, unhandled-exception

I am building an app to store vehicles, I have a main form with buttons on it to load individual forms for each type of vehicle (car,truck,bus) they all inherit their main property's from the vehicle class. I also have a 'fleet' class so that all the vehicles can be added to the fleet.

I have managed to get the first one working car, but I am struggling with the second (truck) one, I can click the button the truck form loads and I can input data into the txt boxes but when I click the 'Close' button on the form nothing happens! And when I close the app I get a 'NotImplementedExecption was unhandled'

Any ideas, what am I missing? Cheers in advance....

```
public partial class FrmHireCo : Form
    /*
     * This is the main form for the car hire system.
     * It allows the adding to new cars to the system, and displaying them in the fleet list
     * 
     */
{
    private Fleet myFleet = new Fleet();
    //Fleet object used to store cars

    public FrmHireCo()
    {
        //Default constructor
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void updateFleetList()
    {   
        lstFleet.Items.Clear();
        foreach (Vehicle v in myFleet.fleet)
        {
            lstFleet.Items.Add(v);
        }
    }

    private void btnAddCar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Add a new car
        FrmCar carGui = new FrmCar(); //Form used to add new car
        carGui.ShowDialog();
        Car myCar = carGui.car;         //Get new car from form
        myFleet.addToFleet(myCar);      //Add to fleet list
        updateFleetList();              //Uodate fleet list
    }

    private void lstFleet_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /*
         * This method is used to control the list box
         * It is called when a row is selected by the user, it then displays frmCar
         * with the car details
         */ 
        if (lstFleet.SelectedIndex > -1)
        {
            int index = lstFleet.SelectedIndex;
            Car myCar = myFleet.fleet.ElementAt(index);
            FrmCar carGui = new FrmCar();
            carGui.car = myCar;
            carGui.Show();
        }
    }

    private void FrmHireCo_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnAddTruck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FrmTruck truckGui = new FrmTruck(); //Form used to add new car
        truckGui.ShowDialog();
        Truck myTruck = truckGui.truck;         //Get new car from form
        myFleet.addToFleet(myTruck);      //Add to fleet list
        updateFleetList();              //Uodate fleet list
    }

}
```

}
}

That is my main form with the buttons to load the truck form etc, here is my fleet class. I think I am missing something really silly!

```
class Fleet
{
    /*
     * This class is used to hold a list of Car objects that make up the fleet:
     * The car objects may be added through the addToFleet() method.
     * The car objects may be deleted tgrough the deleteFromFleet() method 
     * Use the fleet property to access the list of car objects
     */ 

    private List<Vehicle> theFleet = new List<Vehicle>(); //The list of car objects being stored

    public List<Vehicle> fleet 
        /* The fleet property. Note that you can only read it
         * use the addToFleet and deleteFromFleet to update it
         */
    {
        get
        {
            return theFleet;
        }
    }

    public void deleteFromFleet(Vehicle aVehicle)
        //Delete car from fleet
    {
        theFleet.Remove(aVehicle);
    }

    public void addToFleet(Vehicle aVehicle)
        //Add car to fleet
    {
        theFleet.Add(aVehicle);
    }

    internal void addToFleet(Truck myTruck)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

}

This is the part of code in debugging mode that brings up the 'NotImplementedException was unhandled.

```
 internal void addToFleet(Truck myTruck)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: So go give that function a proper implementation?

Comment: Tagged this as homework, since it blatantly is.

Comment: Yes, it's allowed. You should just be up front about it. The good thing is that you're not asking everyone to do your homework for you. You have demonstrated that you've attempted something by yourself and are asking for help with a specific issue. You have done nothing wrong :) Just bear in mind that in future if it's homework you're doing, just let everyone know by adding the `homework` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You would be best off just using code like this:

```
myFleet.fleet.Add(myTruck);
```

than using your own custom add/remove functions which simply call those functions anyway.  You have no hidden them if that was your intent.

As for why you are getting this problem... you should look up overload resolution and remember that internal means anything in the same assembly can access it, so as long as those two classes are in the same exact assembly, you will continue having this problem.

Comment: in each of your button click handlers replacing the code where you currently call your own add/remove functions.

Comment: The same error comes up now  but its behind my 'btnAddTruck' button which is on the main form.

FrmTruck truckGui = new FrmTruck(); //Form used to add new car
            truckGui.ShowDialog();
            Truck myTruck = truckGui.truck;         
            myFleet.addToFleet(myTruck); <<THIS LINE HAS THE ERROR     
            updateFleetList();

Comment: Can you show us the declarations of the Car/Vehicle/Truck classes (ie. the inheritance hierarchy)?

Comment: Just post a stack trace, it will help everyone.  If you are having trouble finding it, when Visual Studio pops up with the error message, just dig into it until you find the stack trace.

Comment: I am a newbie don't know what you mean NickLarsen. OJ - the Vehicle is the super class and all the other classes Car,Truck,Minibus inherite from vehicle. And as I have explained I have a fleet class that is ment to add them to a list box

Answer (score 1):

When you add a truck to your fleet, you're actually calling `internal void addToFleet(Truck myTruck)` not `public void addToFleet(Vehicle aVehicle)` because the compiler is calling the method that matches the type that you're passing in.

Ditch the `internal` method.

Comment: Does everything else look ok in the code for it to do what I want? I have been staring at it for so long I can think about it logically, and I am fairly new to programming!

Comment: You are doubling the work needed when the add/remove functions are already exposed on the `Fleet` property.

Comment: I partly agree with Nick, it just depends on what you want your fleet container to do. If it's going to operate as a bucket of vehicles and nothing more then, as Nick says, using a list directly is enough. If you want a class that has more intelligence, then keep your fleet class and add fleet-specific knowledge to that.

Comment: I maybe never explained it clear enough; Cheers for the time aswell guys! I have a vehicle superclass, I have car,truck,minibus inheriting from vehicle. I then want to add everything into a fleet which I have a class for. I then want them displayed in a listbox....

Comment: @bettsy583, answer this question: why do you have 2 separate functions, 1 for adding ALL vehicles, and one for adding a specific type of vehicle?

Comment: I dont know as I said I am adapting someone elses code, could you advise of a betterv way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like at some point Visual Studio prompted you to "Generate method stub for 'addToFleet' in 'Fleet'", and you said yes. When Visual Studio generates a method for you, it puts `throw new NotImplementedException();` inside as a reminder that you need to go back and implement the method. So normally you would just delete the line that throws the exception and replace it with whatever code belongs in the method.

However, in your case I don't think you need that method at all. I assume that Truck inherits from Vehicle; if so, the overload of addToFleet that takes a Vehicle will work for Trucks as well. So you can just delete the entire `internal void addToFleet(Truck myTruck)` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
internal void addToFleet(Truck myTruck) 
{ 
    throw new NotImplementedException(); 
}
```

Apparently, you've glossed right over the part of your code where the function is implemented.  Simply replace "throw new NotImplementedException" with your code.

Comment: I replaced it with 'theFleet.Add(aVehicle); now I get 'The name 'aVehicle' does not exist in the current context

Comment: what is "aVehicle"?  Have you created it?

Comment: replace it with `theFleet.Add(myTruck);`

Comment: Ok, thats took away that error. In the error list, but when I put it in debugging mode it still does the same thing.....

Comment: No I dont think I have created 'aVehicle' I am adapting someone else coding and trying to work about and add to it. There is one 'aCar' so I pressumed 'aVehicle' and have the other classes inherited from it.